# Problema al llamar a metodos de un fragment desde otro

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

les comento que vengo realizando un proyecto a partir de una tabbed activity, donde las pestañas estan basadas en fragments. En una de los fragments tengo tres elementos CheckBox, y lo que quiero hacer es deshabilitar estos CheckBox desde otro  fragment. He intentado dos metodos pero ninguna me ha resultado. Dejo el codigo de los metodos a los que quiero llamar.

```
public static CheckBox checkDate,checkTime,checkMemory;

public static void setCheckDate(boolean enable) {
    checkDate.setEnabled(enable);
}
public static void setCheckTime(boolean enable) {
    checkTime.setEnabled(enable);
}
public static void setCheckMemory(boolean enable) {
    checkMemory.setEnabled(enable);
}
```

El primer metodo que use, en el otro fragment.

```
SettingsFragment.setCheckDate(false);
SettingsFragment.setCheckTime(false);
SettingsFragment.setCheckMemory(false)
```

El segundo metodo que use:

```
SettingsFragment setCheckBox = (SettingsFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
setCheckBox.setCheckDate(false);
setCheckBox.setCheckTime(false);
setCheckBox.setCheckMemory(false);
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema por favor. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Para poder ayudarte tienes que agregar el código de la actividad que tiene el tabbed activity y de los fragmento que esta contiene.

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude encontrar otra manera de poder deshabilitar los checkBox, sin necesidad de llamar a los metodos esto a traves de SharedPreferences, el codigo que use es el siguiente.

En el fragment donde se encuentran los checkBox la deshabilitacion de los mismos dependera de la bandera 'disable',

```
    SharedPreferences disableCheckBox = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("disableCheckBox",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean disabled = disableCheckBox.getBoolean("disableCheck",true);
    if(!disabled) {
        checkDate.setEnabled( false );
        checkTime.setEnabled( false );
        checkMemory.setEnabled( false );
    }
```

Si en el otro fragment modificamos el valor de 'disableCheck' a false, ya se podra deshabilitar los checkBox para una segunda vez que ejecutemos el fragment donde se encuentran.

```
SharedPreferences disableCheckBox = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("disableCheckBox",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = disableCheckBox .edit();
editor.putBoolean("disableCheck",false);
editor.commit();
```